# SQL query in pandas: Concat multiple rows in column based on a combination of other columns

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation, group-concat

This is response from one sql query in pandas. I want to concatenate, "Label column", together based on Issue and client.
I tried Group By, but is only works with integer values.
Any idea, how I can do this?
Pandas based solution should also be fine.

I tried `.groupby`, in pandas too, command and output below, it only gives me a subset of needed dataframe.

Is it possible to update the `label` column against each `Issue` in first dataframe and removed duplicates and get output as expected below?

SQL Version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014
```

Output:

|  | Issue | Subject | type | Team | Sub Team | Client | Priority | CreatedOn | Label | BuiltOn | CreatedBy | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | ABCABC | Bug | Develop | Automation | Andy | 0 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement | None | John | InProgress |
| 1 | 2 | DEFDEF | Bug | Develop | Automation | Judy | 0 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | Feature | None | Andre | New |
| 2 | 3 | HIGHIG | Bug | Develop | Testing123 | Cathy | 2 | 2021-02-11 00:00:00 | Feature | None | Keith | New |
| 3 | 3 | HIGHIG | Bug | Develop | Testing123 | Cathy | 2 | 2021-02-11 00:00:00 | Internal | None | Keith | New |
| 4 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Jack | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 5 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Jack | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 6 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Larry | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 7 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Larry | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 8 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Colin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 9 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Colin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 10 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Nitin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 11 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Nitin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 12 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Lisa | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 13 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Lisa | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |

Expected (Note the label column):

|  | Issue | Subject | Issue_type | Team | Sub Team | Client | Priority | CreatedOn | Label | BuiltOn | CreatedBy | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | ABC | Bug | Develop | Automation | Andy | 0 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement | None | John | InProgress |
| 1 | 2 | DEF | Bug | Develop | Automation | Judy | 0 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | Feature | None | Andre | New |
| 2 | 3 | HIG | Bug | Develop | Testing | Cathy | 2 | 2021-02-11 00:00:00 | Feature, Internal | None | Keith | New |
| 3 | 4 | XYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Jack | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement, Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 4 | 4 | XYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Larry | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement, Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 5 | 4 | XYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Colin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement, Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 6 | 4 | XYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Nitin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement, Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |
| 7 | 4 | XYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Lisa | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | Enhancement, Internal | None | Maya | Analysis |

**Update:**
This is they query:

```
SELECT I.Issue,
       I.Subject,
       I.type, 
       P.Team, 
       P.Subteam,
       CR.Client,
       I.Priority,
       I.CreatedOn,
       L.Label,
       I.BuiltOn,
       I.CreatedBy,
       I.Status
 FROM master.IssueRequests AS I 
 JOIN master.Participants AS P 
   ON P.Issue = I.Issue 
 JOIN master.ClientRecords AS CR 
   ON CR.Issue = I.Issue 
 JOIN master.IssueLabels AS L
   ON L.Issue = I.Issue
 WHERE I.Issue IN ('2652523', '2703670', '2984120')
```

**Update2**
Output of `df.groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['Issue', 'Client'])['Label'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

|  | Issue | Client | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Andy | Enhancement |
| 1 | 2 | Judy | Feature |
| 2 | 3 | Cathy | Feature,Internal |
| 3 | 4 | Colin | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | 4 | Jack | Enhancement,Internal |
| 5 | 4 | Larry | Enhancement,Internal |
| 6 | 4 | Lisa | Enhancement,Internal |
| 7 | 4 | Nitin | Enhancement,Internal |

Clarification: Merging on all columns except `Label` will not work since in some cases, some of the other data might be "null" or different, which can cause data to be missed altogether. If the data is different in other columns, I can keep the first instance of that data.

Comment: please also show us the query

Comment: in pandas, groupby can be used on non numeric columns

Comment: @Squirrel, added the query

Comment: @EmiOB, added pandas groupby result too

Comment: @akshat what do you want to happen to the other columns? Is priority the average? and which created on date do you want to be kept? same with createdby and status etc

Comment: @EmiOB, want to keep them as is, no operations on them

Comment: @akshat then you need to add them to your groupby too.

Comment: @EmiOB, that does not work in all cases, just gave a comment on buddemat's answer below.

Comment: Then your question needs to be edited and @EmiOB's question needs an answer. What do you want to happen with the other columns if the data is different? You cannot just _keep them_ if they should be grouped...

Comment: @buddemat, if the data is different in other columns, I can keep the first instance of that data. Adding 50 columns to the question will too much, ill try to find the example columns from the data and update.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
After clarification of the OP, it seems that the problem actually is a bit different: The columns' contents except the grouping columns `Issue` and `Client` may actually differ between grouped rows and the final result should contain the first row's value for columns that differ between such grouped rows.

An approach to do this could be to perform the grouping in Python as you did before and then join (using `merge()`) that with a version of the original dataframe in which you drop all duplicates based on `Issue` and `Client` (as well as the `Label` column). That gives you exactly the first instance for each grouped row in case data differs.

Without additional arguments, `merge()` will automatically do an inner join on all columns available in both dataframes, which in this case are `Issue` and `Client`:

```python
df.groupby(['Issue', 'Client'])['Label'].apply(','.join).reset_index().merge(df.drop('Label', axis=1).drop_duplicates(['Issue', 'Client']))
```

Output:

|  | Issue | Subject | type | Team | Sub Team | Client | Priority | CreatedOn | BuiltOn | CreatedBy | Status | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | ABCABC | Bug | Develop | Automation | Andy | 0 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 | None | John | InProgress | Enhancement |
| 1 | 2 | DEFDEF | Bug | Develop | Automation | Judy | 0 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | None | Andre | New | Feature |
| 2 | 3 | HIGHIG | Bug | Develop | Testing123 | Cathy | 2 | 2021-02-11 00:00:00 | None | Keith | New | Feature,Internal |
| 3 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Colin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Jack | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 5 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Larry | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 6 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Lisa | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 7 | 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Nitin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |

---

**Previous answer**:

Just group by all of the other columns:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'ABCABC', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Andy', 0, '2021-01-11 00:00:00', 'Enhancement', 'None', 'John', 'InProgress'],
[2, 'DEFDEF', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Judy', 0, '2021-01-10 00:00:00', 'Feature', 'None', 'Andre', 'New'],
[3, 'HIGHIG', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Testing123', 'Cathy', 2, '2021-02-11 00:00:00', 'Feature', 'None', 'Keith', 'New'],
[3, 'HIGHIG', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Testing123', 'Cathy', 2, '2021-02-11 00:00:00', 'Internal', 'None', 'Keith', 'New'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Jack', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Enhancement', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Jack', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Internal', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Larry', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Enhancement', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Larry', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Internal', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Colin', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Enhancement', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Colin', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Internal', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Nitin', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Enhancement', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Nitin', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Internal', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Lisa', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Enhancement', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis'],
[4, 'XYZXYZ', 'Bug', 'Develop', 'Automation', 'Lisa', 1, '2021-05-11 00:00:00', 'Internal', 'None', 'Maya', 'Analysis']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Issue', 'Subject', 'type', 'Team', 'Sub Team', 'Client', 'Priority', 'CreatedOn', 'Label', 'BuiltOn', 'CreatedBy', 'Status']) 

df.groupby(['Issue', 'Subject', 'type', 'Team', 'Sub Team', 'Client', 'Priority', 'CreatedOn', 'BuiltOn', 'CreatedBy', 'Status'])['Label'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

If you don't want to write all column names, you can also use list comprehension to automatically build the list and exclude just the `Label` column from it, similar to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606701/14015737):

```python
df.groupby([col for col in list(df) if col not in ['Label']])['Label'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: I tried this too, however, there are two issues with this, in my actual dataframe, there are  more 50 columns, and I have multiple such queries. So it is quite error prone to write and all columns. also, in some cases, some of the other data might be "null" or different. which can causes data to be missed all together.

Comment: Well, then please edit your question so that your example data and your question reflect that and tell us, how you would the result to look like when the data are different.

Comment: I modified my answer to fir your revised problem description.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a second approach using SQL.

Concatenating strings in a `GROUP BY` is a bit tricky in MS Sql Server, since there is no direct function as in other RDBMS. However, there [is a workaround using `FOR XML` and `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273330/14015737) that can be adapted to your problem.

The following statement gives you the concatenated labels based on your original query:

```sql
WITH tmp AS (SELECT I.Issue,
                    I.Subject,
                    I.type, 
                    P.Team, 
                    P.Subteam,
                    CR.Client,
                    I.Priority,
                    I.CreatedOn,
                    L.Label,
                    I.BuiltOn,
                    I.CreatedBy,
                    I.Status
              FROM master.IssueRequests AS I 
              JOIN master.Participants AS P 
                ON P.Issue = I.Issue 
              JOIN master.ClientRecords AS CR 
                ON CR.Issue = I.Issue 
              JOIN master.IssueLabels AS L
                ON L.Issue = I.Issue
              WHERE I.Issue IN ('2652523', '2703670', '2984120')
)
SELECT A.Issue,
       A.Client,
       STUFF((
           SELECT ', ' + B.Label 
             FROM tmp B 
            WHERE ISNULL(B.Issue, '') = ISNULL(A.Issue, '')
              AND ISNULL(B.Client, '') = ISNULL(A.Client, '')
         ORDER BY B.Issue 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
    ) AS Label
FROM
    tmp A
GROUP BY 
    A.Issue, A.Client
```

This gives you

| Issue | Client | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | Enhancement |
| 2 | Judy | Feature |
| 3 | Cathy | Feature,Internal |
| 4 | Colin | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | Jack | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | Larry | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | Lisa | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | Nitin | Enhancement,Internal |

You can then [use `ROW_NUMBER()` to `JOIN` this with the first row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798485/14015737) of each `Issue`-`Client`-combination:

```sql
WITH tmp AS (SELECT I.Issue,
                    I.Subject,
                    I.type, 
                    P.Team, 
                    P.Subteam,
                    CR.Client,
                    I.Priority,
                    I.CreatedOn,
                    L.Label,
                    I.BuiltOn,
                    I.CreatedBy,
                    I.Status
              FROM master.IssueRequests AS I 
              JOIN master.Participants AS P 
                ON P.Issue = I.Issue 
              JOIN master.ClientRecords AS CR 
                ON CR.Issue = I.Issue 
              JOIN master.IssueLabels AS L
                ON L.Issue = I.Issue
              WHERE I.Issue IN ('2652523', '2703670', '2984120')
)
SELECT C.Issue,
       C.Subject,
       C.typ, 
       C.Team, 
       C.Subteam,
       C.Client,
       C.Priority,
       C.CreatedOn,
       D.Label,
       C.BuiltOn,
       C.CreatedBy,
       C.Status  
  FROM (SELECT tmp.*, 
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Issue, Client ORDER BY Issue) as rn
        FROM tmp) C
  JOIN (SELECT A.Issue,
               A.Client,
               STUFF((
                   SELECT ', ' + B.Label 
                     FROM tmp B 
                    WHERE ISNULL(B.Issue, '') = ISNULL(A.Issue, '')
                      AND ISNULL(B.Client, '') = ISNULL(A.Client, '')
                 ORDER BY B.Issue 
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
            ) AS Label
        FROM tmp A
        GROUP BY A.Issue, A.Client) D
   ON C.Issue = D.Issue AND C.Client = D.Client AND C.rn = 1
```

which gives you your desired result:

| Issue | Subject | type | Team | Sub Team | Client | Priority | CreatedOn | BuiltOn | CreatedBy | Status | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCABC | Bug | Develop | Automation | Andy | 0 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 | None | John | InProgress | Enhancement |
| 2 | DEFDEF | Bug | Develop | Automation | Judy | 0 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | None | Andre | New | Feature |
| 3 | HIGHIG | Bug | Develop | Testing123 | Cathy | 2 | 2021-02-11 00:00:00 | None | Keith | New | Feature,Internal |
| 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Colin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Jack | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Larry | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Lisa | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |
| 4 | XYZXYZ | Bug | Develop | Automation | Nitin | 1 | 2021-05-11 00:00:00 | None | Maya | Analysis | Enhancement,Internal |

You can test it in [this db<>dfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3bf241a51178265027a244011e9d943d)